# How does CTC work in Speech Recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition

I have already read the 2006 Paper about CTC by Graves but I still don't understand it fully. I am searching for a simple but still detailed explanation of how "Connectionist Temporal Classification" (CTC) works in Speech Recognition. Especially about how CTC does Backpropagation about all possible alignments and derives a final transcription of that.

Comment: as a starting point, have a look at: https://towardsdatascience.com/3797e43a86c
Then, read the more in-depth explanation at: https://distill.pub/2017/ctc/
Finally, go back to the original paper and have a close look at how the alpha and beta variables are computed.
With these variables, you're able to compute the derivative of the text-probability p(l|x) with regard to the label probability at a given time-step y_k^t.